# Modern Era UITableView Animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

In a `UITableView` what would be the most convenient way of showing up additional information from a smooth scrolling effect?

You might want to look at the screenshot below. The top `UITableViewCell` is a kind of "Create new stuff"-button field, and I would like a formular to show up from below this field with a smooth uniform scroll animation.

How is this best achieved? Do I want to create a view and manipulate with the current cell's height and animate+display a `SubView` or do I want to manipulate with the `Delegate` and `DataSource` to simply create a condition on showing more cells if the button is pressed (which causes a `reloadData` with some kind of animation set true) ?

I could wander around in the wilderness and mess around, but I guess that I'm not the first one to encounter such issue and that someone might have some constructive input.

[image: in-app screenshot]

** UPDATE **
All the interesting stuff happens in `indexPath.section = 0` so I now simply created an `(atomic) BOOL createFormActive` and manipulate cell data accordingly with my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` looking something like this:

```
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        self.createFormActive = !self.createFormActive;
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
```

This works pretty well. So you could say I have found a solution, but feel free to use this thread as inspiration or discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results with the "showing more cells if the button is pressed" approach. Relying on the table view's built-in animations is good bang for the buck IMO. Initially, however, I found managing a dynamic data model and calculating the batch updates can get out of hand quickly.

I ended up writing the [TLIndexPathTools framework](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) to make these things easy. Take a look at the [Settings example project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Settings/Settings/SettingsTableViewController.m), a "settings" table view that morphs into a couple of different configurations as you make selections. I've done a much more elaborate real-world settings screen with table animation and it turned out very well.